# What are the sample points in sample space? What is the random variable?

Tags: operations-research, queueing-theory

As we know that interarrival time in queueing theory  follows exponential distribution. I want to know what are the sample points and what is random variable corresponding to interarrival time? As when we toss a coin then sample points are clear. But in internal arrival time I am unable to find sample point. If someone explain this with example then it would be great help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off, interarrival times (IATs) do not always follow an exponential distribution. In an M/M/n queue, they do (that's the first "M"). In real life, not so much. That said, to get sample points you just park someone at the entry point of the queue who records when each successive customer shows up. The difference between the time the system opens and the time the first customer arrives is the first IAT. The difference between when the first customer got there and when the second customer got there is the second IAT, and so on.